# cannot version bump on push to production

Tags: github, github-actions

In Github actions when the production branch is protected with checks,
on migration after the check pass there is a rule that should update the .version number.
the error that happening is missing
This operation push file into the protected branch. but the operation try to request for approvals!

> remote: error: 2 of 2 required status checks are expected. At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.

The task should allow my request, I was trying to use many methods the execute the version bump after the step test finish but the protect branch do not allow.

note: I was saw many question on this topic and non from the solutions solve this issue, to allow update protected branch after migration.

Comment: I don't know about GitHub specifically, but one general solution for this is to allow specific users to bypass branch policies/protection, and have that user do the push.

Comment: where is it ? for sure this is going to great if i could find this

Comment: Questions about GitHub actions are specific to GitHub; they're not general Git questions. Questions about GitHub branch protection features are specific to GitHub: Git has no branch protection, that's a GitHub add-on.

Comment: In the end i have solved my issue by removing the push to protected branch after check (and only bump tag). After that aws codepipeline did full clone and update the codebuild to have role codestar(allow to use git commands) the git commands git the tag name and the sha. Mission success